# изменение переменной PHP

Tags: php, html

Как присвоить `text` в
`<input type="text" value="+1" name="n">`
значению переменной `$a`

Comment: Можно прочитать на официальном сайте PHP инструкцию о том, [как это делается](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.external.php]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос. Text в Input - это **тип** поля или **содержимое** поля, вы имеете в виду?

В любом случае, вот ответ для изменения **содержимого**. В случае с типом просто переместите переменную в нужное место: *(в type вместо value)*

```
<?php
    $a = "Some text";
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$a.'" name="n">';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше использовать разрыв тегов

```
<input type="text" value="+1" name="<?php echo $a ?>">
```

А вот более короткий синтаксис, он используется для шаблонизации

```
<input type="text" value="+1" name="<?= $a ?>">
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, почему этот способ лучше?

Comment: Намного более читаемый, позволяет избавитсья от бесконечной вложености кавычек и необходимости следить за экранированием.